# Typescript - Filter a generic array type by element type

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have an array of values:

```js
const array = ['b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'] as const;
```

So the type is:

```js
const array: readonly ["b", "a", "b", "a", "c"]
```

Now I want to create a type that filters the array, and returns a type of array with only the filtered elements. I've created a `FilterArray` type, that does the trick, however, the indexes on the array are taken from the first array and not restarted.

```js
type FilterArray<T extends readonly any[], V> = {
    [I in keyof T as [Extract<T[I], V>] extends [never] ? never : I]: T[I];
}
```

If I filter now on `typeof array`, I get these results:
[image: filter results]
`filteredArray[3]` is also of type 'a', which is correct.

Is it possible to restart the index from 0? Or should I take another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as). Because of the *key remapping*, the resulting type of `FilterArray` is not a *tuple* but an **object** type with the two properties `1` and `3`.

To get a *tuple* type as the result, you need a recursive type.

```
type FilterArray<T extends readonly any[], V> = 
  T extends readonly [infer L, ...infer R]
    ? L extends V
      ? [L, ...FilterArray<R, V>]
      : [...FilterArray<R, V>]
    : []
```

This type iterates through the array and adds matching elements to the output.

The resulting type would now look like this:

```
const filteredArray = {} as FilterArray<typeof array, "a">
//    ^? ["a", "a"]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=9&pln=3&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gcgEY4A0MOcRJBxp5OwOAuvBDKJFANwCwAUD1CgAcApjABiASwA2UIQgCCSVAB4AKjCEAPGWAAmzBELg7wktHDAos9YgDUAfBhg8YMNZu16YBoybRZxYABmsjAAMsQAdFEBwQgwAEr0zi4wAPxh6lpCusw2ySlp2OEwURES0rIKyChK8bZ2SdwFLgBc2KXlMvKKNXUw9o0FbVY8PKzQMIFSXUI6VaiOAN4Avkxi05U9SvzCIIHwPcQARHBHdjwA9BcFAHrpWCdHx6f0QA)

Comment: Thank you very much! That works as expected. Do you know what are the performance implications of this type?

Comment: @SebastianAlex Well it's not using tail call optimization but other than that it's as fast as it can get. Obviously like any overengineered type it will be pretty slow given large inputs.

Comment: And also key remapping can result in the original tuple type. It's just that they are removing keys so the result isn't a tuple.

Comment: @kelly - Ah, I see. I am not really sure what the rule is here. When does is stay a tuple and when does it become an object?

Comment: Oh I just fiddled around and it seems that *any* form of key remapping makes it become an object. Even `[K in keyof A as K]: ...`, where there is no effect from key remapping, makes it become an object.

Comment: @kelly - I just tested `[I in keyof T as I]` and it seems to be a tuple. Has all the array props and all.

Comment: In the tooltip does the type show as `[...]` or `{ [x: number]: ...; 0: ...; 1: ...; ... }`? https://tsplay.dev/WYZLbw

Comment: @kelly - Oh I was using a generic type and when hovering over it, it would not show the real type. Only  `FilterArray<readonly ["b", "a", "b", "a", "c"], "a">`. So it probably is an object type too.